# "Universal" links in HTML?

Tags: html, universal

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Include one HTML file in another HTML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336569/include-one-html-file-in-another-html-file)

On each of the pages on my website I have a footer that contains about 12 links. Every time I want to change a link, I have to do it on every single page. Is it possible to make it so I can somehow change the link in one place and it changes on every page? Thanks.

Comment: that sounds like a problem from the 1980ies :D Have you looked into trying a server-side scripting language?

Comment: It sounds like that because it is like that lol. Yeah someone suggested it below, I just hadn't thought of it before he said it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This exact problem is the beauty of serverside scripting, where you can define a header file that each page pulls from when it is retrieved, allowing you to change a single file and have the changes propagate your entire website.

This is what it could look like in PHP:

header.php - `<a href="link">Link</a>`

all_other_pages.php - `<?php include header.php; ?> ...`

Answer (score 2):

the better approach is use the mvc architecture  for that . and you can do it by creating the separate php file and include them

like for header header.php for wrapper wrapper.php  and for footer footer.php and to show a pagge just include or require them

like index.php

```
   <?php
     require"header.php"; // for the header of the page 
     require"wrapper.php";
     require"footer.php";  // for the footer of the page
```

you can also make function of `header()` and `footer()` so you can also include many more function in a file and it reduce the amount of file also you only need to include the one file with function

index.php

```
 <?php
      require"function.php"; 
      header();      // for the header of the page           
      require"wrapper.php";
      footer();       // for the footer of the page
```

in above approach the code of header and futtor will be universal for all website what you need to change is the chande the code in wrapper.php

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to do server side programming to fix this (though you can do), you can do it perfectly fine in the browser with a little javascript.

For example:
at the bottom of each page:

```
<div class="page-footer"/>
<script src="footer.js"></script>
```

in footer.js something along the lines:

```
$(".page-footer").append("<ul><li><a href='about.html'>About</a></li></ul>");
```

Comment: could you show   how to do this ? and also is it more time and code saving way to do this than by server side including separate files like in my file

Comment: Well the thing is I would go with that but some people disable JavaScript so in the long run it's probably better to go with PHP.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use a server side include or other server side programming then yes, otherwise it isn't posible with straight HTML. You could include the footer in an IFRAME such that each page loads the same footer page, but this is far from an ideal solution.