# HTML inherit main html with menus

Tags: html, inheritance

I want to build a website with 30 html pages. They all are going to have left menu and top menu always the same so i would like to define those menus in only one html and inherit that html in all other html pages.

Is this possible? How is it done?

I was looking for a solution without using php.

Regards,

Comment: Use PHP, [SSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes) ... You can also do with JS but don't depend much on client side for core layout processing

Comment: possible duplicate of [Include one HTML file in another HTML file using server side include](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336569/include-one-html-file-in-another-html-file-using-server-side-include)

Answer (score 0):

You could use frames, but that's a bad method as its old and outdated now.

Your better solution would be to use PHP and have the menus as separate files and just 'link' them to the main page by using the `include` function

Ie

```
<html>
<head>
<?php include 'head.php'; ?>
</head>
</html>
```

And then your head.php file could include your title tag and anything else that may go in the head tag.

That way you only have to make one change to the site title for it to affect all the pages the include is featured in.

Comment: sorry, i edited my question: i was looking for a solution without using php

Comment: You would be best to start looking for a solution with PHP, as it's the only true way to handle it cleanly, and it working for pretty much everyone. HTML is only static web pages, unless you use javascript. But that's only client side. PHP is your solution.